# Additive endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to find all additive endomorphisms of ${\Bbb{Z}}$.

I checked that given an integer $m$, the function $f:{\Bbb{Z}}\to{\Bbb{Z}}$ defined by $f(x) = mx$ is an additive endomorphism. I suspect that every such endomorphism has the form above but I don't know how to prove it.

So, how can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Show that $f$ is uniquely determined by $f(1)$. Hint: $f(1+\ldots+1)=f(1)+\ldots +f(1)$.